# Aurelia: unit-testing Event Aggregator

Tags: unit-testing, aurelia

As an Angular (2) developer, I recently started experimenting with Aurelia. Really like it by the way..
But I really have some difficulties unit-testing Aurelia's `Event Aggregator`. This is what I have currently, but it doesn't fire the event in my controller right now. I now I'm doing it wrong, some help would be great!

```
// app.js

@inject(UserService, EventAggregator)
export class App {
    constructor(userService, eventAggregator) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.authorizedUser = null;

        // get authorized user
        this.getAuthorizedUser();

        // subscribe to events
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe(EVENTS.USER_LOGGED_IN, data => {
            this.authorizedUser = data;
        });
    }

    // calls userService and sets this.authorizedUser;
    getAuthorizedUser() {
        ....
    }
 }
```

And my spec currently looks like this:

```
describe('app', () => {
    let component,
        createComponent,
        eventAggregator = new EventAggregator(),
        userService = new UserService();

    beforeEach(() => {    
        component = StageComponent.withResources('app').inView('<app></app>');
        component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
            aurelia.use.standardConfiguration();
            aurelia.container.registerInstance(UserService, userService);
            aurelia.container.registerInstance(EventAggregator, eventAggregator);
        });

        createComponent = component.create(bootstrap);
    });

    // this one is working for example..
    it('should get authorized user when token is set', (done) => {
        const result = 'some value';

        spyOn(UserService, 'getToken').and.returnValue(true);
        spyOn(userService, 'getAuthorizedUser').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('some value'));

        createComponent.then(() => {
            const viewModel = component.viewModel;
            expect(viewModel.authorizedUser).toEqual(result);
            done();
        });
    });

    // this one is failing (depending on Event Aggregator)
    it('should set authorized user when LOGGED_IN event is fired', (done) => {
        spyOn(UserService, 'getToken').and.returnValue(false);

        createComponent.then(() => {
            const viewModel = component.viewModel;
            expect(viewModel.authorizedUser).toEqual(null);

            eventAggregator.publish(EVENTS.USER_LOGGED_IN, 'some value');
            expect(viewModel.authorizedUser).toEqual('some value');
            done();
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        component.dispose();
    });


});
```

Comment: Did you check the instances of EventAggregator? Are they for sure the same? I guess they should, as you register an instance of it. However, you may try `registerSingleton()`, although I think it should make no difference.

Comment: The issue is because you're using `new EventAggregator`. Your classes need to be using the __same__ instance of the EventAggregator class. Also - I'm guessing `EVENTS.USER_LOGGED_IN` is a string of some sort?

Comment: @thebluefox Thanks for your reply, yes it's a string imported from as a constant. Also updated answered my question with a (for me) working solution. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

So after some trial and error, I found out how to unit-test the code above. It's not really following Aurelia's docs, but I'm actually very pleased with this way of testing. Hope this may help some of you. Don't know of this is the correct way, but it works for me. Please comment your thoughts..

```
describe('app', () => {
    let sut,
        userServiceMock,
        eventAggregator;

    beforeEach(() => {
        userServiceMock = new UserServiceMock(); // use a mock for the original service
        eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        sut = new App(userServiceMock, eventAggregator);
    });

    describe('subscribing to events', () => {

        it('should set authorized user when LOGGED_IN event is fired', done => {
            const authUser = {someKey: 'someValue'};

            // expect initial values
            expect(sut.authorizedUser).toEqual(null);

            // publish an event     
            eventAggregator.publish(EVENTS.USER_LOGGED_IN, authUser);
                                 // ^ this is just a string constant

            // expect the values changes triggered by the event
            expect(sut.authorizedUser).toEqual(authUser);

            done();
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // sut.dispose() doesn't work here, still need to figure this out
    });

});
```